# Python requests suddenly don't work anymore with a specific url

Tags: python, python-requests

Until recently, the following worked fine:

```
import requests
page = requests.get("https://www.moviemeter.nl/")
```

but not anymore. Now I am getting back a result <Response [200]>, page.ok = True but page.text is an empty string. Getting the page with Google Chrome works fine.

I tried:

- with or without to the of a vpn
- with headers:
  headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'}
  page = requests.get("http://moviemeter.nl/", headers=headers)
  Nothing seems to work anymore.

Can somebody help me out?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you make your qn more specific ?

Comment: What does Chrome show in Network Tab (F12)? Post more details or your question will be closed.

Comment: Yeah, maybe they have introduced some protection against hackers and scrapers.

Comment: Probably the text is loaded from JavaScript that is loaded in first request.

Comment: The site has probably implemented anti-scraping measures. The strange thing is the network tab in Chrome dev tools shows a response.

Comment: @sashoalm There would have to be **something** in the body of the first request to start any JavaScript or initiate other requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request requires cookies to get the site content.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.moviemeter.nl/"

with requests.session() as session:
    response = session.get(url)
    response = session.get(url, cookies=response.cookies)
    print(response.content)
```

Comment: It works as a charm.  Thank you very much.